# How to refresh cairo drawing in gtk2?

Tags: c, gtk, gnome, cairo, gtk2

I have a problem with refreshing my cairo drawing. It doesn't work and I don't know why. Could you help me? I want to create a new "drawing" whenever analyse function is executed.

I created something like this:

```
d_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
```

Then i packed it in scrolled window:

```
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(formula_scrolled_window), d_area);
```

Then:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(d_area), "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(expose_event_callback), NULL);
```

but before it I have got :

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(search_entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(analyse), &window_and_search_entry);
```

function analyse:

```
ELEMENT *analyse(GtkWidget *widget, WINDOW_AND_SEARCH_ENTRY *data)
{
    const gchar *text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(data->search_entry));
    main_window = data->window;
    d_area = GTK_DRAWING_AREA(data->d_area); //do I nedd it?


    foo = operate(text, GTK_WIDGET(data->window));

    print_on_console_with_new_line(foo);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(d_area), "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(expose_event_callback), NULL); //do I need it??
    do_drawing(cr, foo); //is it good 
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(d_area), "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(expose_event_callback), NULL); //do I need it??


}
```

And:

```
gboolean expose_event_callback (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{


  cr = gdk_cairo_create (gtk_widget_get_window (widget)); 
  do_drawing(cr, foo);
  return FALSE;
}
```

Finally:

```
void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr, ELEMENT *p) 
{
gdouble font_size = 20.0;

cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
cairo_set_font_size(cr, font_size);


cairo_move_to(cr, lala, 30.0);
cairo_show_text(cr, "6");  
lala += 30;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? is it drawing on top of the previous image?

Comment: It doesn't draw a new image. I am seeing still the same. I want to have a function which will be updating the cairo image.

Comment: These two solutions work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this at the begining of the `do_drawing()` function

```
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1., 1., 1.); 
cairo_paint(cr);
```

and also to your gtk widget do this to update it

```
gtk_widget_queue_draw(formula_scrolled_window);
```